# How to recall a function with Jquery in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to recall a function and have the 
dialog box keep coming back when click 'cancel' button with Jquery in this example?
I am sure it is easy but still learning some of the basics here.
Thanks

```
function definitelyClose() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com'
};
var autoCloseTimer;
var timeoutObject;
var timePeriod = 5000;
var warnPeriod = 10000;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#proba').dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#proba').attr('title', 'Warning').text('Sesion will expire').dialog('open');
        $('#proba').dialog({
            buttons: {
                'Cancel': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    clearTimeout(autoCloseTimer);
                }
            }
        });
        autoCloseTimer = setTimeout('definitelyClose()', warnPeriod);
    }, timePeriod);
});​
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your Javascript console?

Comment: No error at all. The code is running but i can't make it re run again? The clearTimeout function does not seems to do the job!

Comment: How do you mean re run? It will only run at `$(document).ready` right?

Comment: well i would like to re-run that everytime i click on cancel button? how can i do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create function with a name to

1. show the initial warning and
2. to call when the cancel button is clicked.

So you would get something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var autoCloseTimer;
  var timePeriod = 5000;
  var warnPeriod = 10000;

  function definitelyClose() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com'
  };

  // You need a function with a name
  function showWarning() {
    $('#proba').attr('title', 'Warning')
               .text('Sesion will expire')
               .dialog('open');
    $('#proba').dialog({
      buttons: {
        'Cancel': function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
          clearTimeout(autoCloseTimer);
          // Now you can recall the function
          setTimeout(showWarning, timePeriod);
        }
      }
    });
    autoCloseTimer = setTimeout(definitelyClose, warnPeriod);
  }

  $('#proba').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
  setTimeout(showWarning, timePeriod);
});​
```

Comment: That's it. works great. I will have to do some more coding to really get the hang of it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: lastly, i thought that i have to do loop in order to recall the function. i guess with loop would work but it will make it more complicated unnecessarily!